# eigenbasis of old forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $S_k(N)$ be the space of weight $k$ cusp forms with respect to $\Gamma_0(N)$ for $1\leq N\leq 100$.  We have a decomposition:

$$S_k(N)= S_k^{\text{new}}\oplus S_k^{\text{old}}$$
Suppose that we know the eigenbasis of new forms of $S_k(N)$, for all $1\leq N\leq 100$. How do we find  eigenbasis of old forms?

Comment: I do not know why someone vote this down without any comments.

Comment: Perhaps because this is very well explained in the standard references, e.g. William Stein's free e-book "Modular Forms -- A Computational Approach" (try http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/newforms.html#atkin-lehner-li-theory).